# Pass an input value as an argument to function in another thread

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, python-multithreading

I am making a program in Python 3 with tkinter that requires a pause/play button to stop and start a loop. I am doing this using multithreading. The function that runs the loop takes an argument that is a value input by the user.

The example below shows part of the program I am working on. It is based off of this code https://pastebin.com/qC37WJfA.

```
from tkinter import *
import itertools
import threading

global entry_text

#constants for threading
START = 1
STOP = 0
EXIT = -1

looping = STOP

#stores position of pause/play button
toggle_play_pause = itertools.cycle(['playing', 'paused'])

class ThreadingTest():

    def __init__(self, win):
        self.win = win
        self.win.title('Threading Test')

        entry_text = ''

        self.build_play_frame()

        thread = threading.Thread(target=test_loop, args=(entry_text,))
        thread.daemon = True
        thread.start()

    def build_play_frame(self):
        self.play_frame = Frame(self.win, width=150, height=250, padx=20)

        #creating widgets
        self.play_pause_button = Button(self.play_frame, text='play', command=self.on_play_pause_button_clicked)
        self.entry_field = Entry(self.play_frame)

        #mapping widgets to location
        self.play_pause_button.grid(row=1, column=0)
        self.entry_field.grid(row=0, column=0)
        self.play_frame.grid(row=0, column=0)

    #this function is ran when the play/pause button is clicked
    def on_play_pause_button_clicked(self):
        global looping
        global entry_text
        entry_text = self.entry_field.get()
        action = next(toggle_play_pause)
        if action == 'playing':
            self.play_pause_button.config(text='Pause')
            looping = START
        else:
            self.play_pause_button.config(text='Play')
            looping = STOP

def run():
    win = Tk()
    ThreadingTest(win)
    win.mainloop()
    looping = EXIT

def test_loop(text):
    while True:
        if looping == START:
            print(text)
        if looping == EXIT:
            break

if __name__ == '__main__':
    run()
```

The program should take the input from the entry field and keep on printing this value when the pause/play button is clicked until it is clicked again to stop it. The problem is that the variable entry_text does not update and therefore it prints the blank string assigned to it at the start rather than the text in the entry field. I assume this is because the value of the variable rather than the actual variable is passed here.

```
thread = threading.Thread(target=test_loop, args=(entry_text,))
```

Any guidance as to how to get this to work would be very much appreciated.
Many thanks,
Charlie

Comment: The problem with your program is that when defining a function, it takes in the argument as it is. What this means is when you call `thread = threading.Thread(target=test_loop, args=(entry_text,))`, you are running function `test_loop` with argument `''` since `entry_text=''`. I would do the same thing you did with the `looping` variable and have the text printed that way.

Comment: 1) Change `entry_text` to instance variable of `StringVar`: `self.entry_text = StringVar()`; 2) Associate this variable to the `Entry`: `self.entry_field = Entry(self.play_frame, textvariable=self.entry_text)`; 3) Use `print(text.get())` inside `test_loop()`.

Comment: @trigangle With your help I have now got the program to work. Many thanks!

Comment: @acw1668 Thank you for your guidance. That was a great help. Turned out to be much simpler than I thought!